How Elastic Search Composite Aggregation On Whole Index And Return Whole Result
I have tried to call a Composite Aggregation in ES but return only few results, clearly, it only do the composite aggregation on 10 records.
Same ask as title: How Elastic Search Composite Aggregation On Whole Index And Return Whole Result?
Query:

Response:


Please update your question and share as text instead of images so others can find it.

yes, I want to do that, but stack overflow editor alert me said something wrong in the text...


The size parameter can be set to define how many composite buckets
should be returned. Each composite bucket is considered as a single
bucket, so setting a size of 10 will return the first 10 composite
buckets created from the value sources. The response contains the
values for each composite bucket in an array containing the values
extracted from each value source. Defaults to 10.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_size
GET /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 2,   <--- update this
        "sources": [
          { "date": { "date_histogram": { "field": "timestamp", "calendar_interval": "1d" } } },
          { "product": { "terms": { "field": "product" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Update:
Here is an example:
PUT composite/_doc/1
{
  "product": ["foo", "bar"],
  "number": [23, 65, 76, 61, 60, 85]
}


GET composite/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 20, 
        "sources": [
          { "products": { "terms": { "field": "product.keyword" } } },
          { "numbers": { "terms": { "field": "number" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}



Thanks @Musab Dogan, but same result return, after set size to 1000

the size parameter is working fine in my env. I updated the answer and add an example please check and let me know.

I found one very wired issue, the size works, but it not work in kibana dev tool console, it works in java code, and in java code, I found if I add more than 10 composite column, it will reduce the return result, but column is less or equal 10, it will return full result...
